# Make an objects methods chainable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I have been doing battle with this project and understand the concept but cannot get my head wrapped around how to get the end result.

Given this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Make an objects methods chainable </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>

  function modifyFunction(f) {
    return function() {
      var returnValue = f.apply(this, arguments);

       if (returnValue === undefined) {
          return this;
       } else {
          return returnValue;
       }
     };
   }

   function modifyMethod(o, m) {
   // your code here
   //the object being passed is the var o
  //the method being passed is the add or sub functions contained in the
  // var

  var methodIn = o[m]; 
  var objectIn = o;
  var numIn;

  console.log("Method In: " + methodIn);
  console.log("Object In: " + objectIn);

    if (o.hasOwnProperty(m) ) { 
     var property = o[m];   
     console.log(property);
     console.log("o has property " + m); 
     modifyFunction(this);

     if (methodIn instanceof Function) {
     //  if (this instanceof o) {

       modifyFunction(o);
       return this;
       console.log("This after modifyFunction: " + this);
       console.log("after modifyFunction " + this);

     }        
        modifyFunction(m);   
      } 

 if (!o.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
    console.log("Function not contained in Object");
 }


}  

var o = {
  num: 0,
  add: function(x) {
    this.num += x;
 },
  sub: function(x) {
    this.num -= x;
 }
};

 // We cannot chain object o(s) method because they do not return 
 //--this--
 //o.add(4).sub(2); // fail - the methods are not chainable yet!

 // Make the add method chainable.

   modifyMethod(o, "add");

   // Now we can chain the add methods
   o.add(2).add(4);
   //console.log(o.num); // o.num = 6

   // Now make the sub method chainable

   //modifyMethod(o, "sub");

   // Now we can chain both the sub and add methods

  //o.sub(1).add(3).sub(5);
  //console.log(o.num);  // o.num = 3
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The objective is to use hasOwnProperty and instanceof to check if the object being passed in has the method property being passed in, I understand this and can see the results in the console. The instanceof is supposed to check to see if the property of the object is an instance of a function, I am not too clear on this and keep getting an error message returned (function expected). If I'm understanding this correctly I need to pass the info into the modifyFunction to perform the calculations?

I see the object being passed into the function and the methods (add and sub) functions, but just cannot figure out what I need to do to make it work. I apologize in advance for this code, but can someone help me to understand how to tie "this" all together?

I have looked through all of the postings on this topic but still cannot get it through my head.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to making chaining like `o.add(2).add(4);` work with your own object, then every method that is chainable MUST do `return this` so it returns the object that the next method can be called on.

Comment: See [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions can be passed around like variables in JavaScript, but they're essentially immutable, just like strings. If I gave you this code:

```
a = "my string";
b = a;
```

...and then asked you to change `a` into "your string", but without any `a =` blocks (so, changing the actual "my string" object, and not the reference), then barring some possibly extreme JS-hacking measures, you couldn't do it. They're created, and stay the same - but usually have methods to create similar ones off the existing ones.

Similarly, since you can't "change" a function, `modifyFunction` isn't doing quite what you think it is, because you're not assigning the result of its call to anything. So in some ways what I'm critiquing is a terminology difference - you can't "modify" a function, BUT, you can replace its local reference with one that references the original and does what you'd like. Try replacing this part of your code; and you can remove the other instance of `modifyFunction`

```
if (methodIn instanceof Function) {
 //  if (this instanceof o) {

   o[m] = modifyFunction(m);
   return o;

}
```

Another issue with what you were doing that I noticed late was that you were passing the object into `modifyFunction`, not the method. Additionally, your function isn't being called in the correct manner to use the `this` keyword. It's being called from the global context, so `this` will probably just be `window`. Just change any other necessary references to `this` into `o`, and it should be fine.